# How to delete Hudson workspace before build?

Tags: java, build, hudson

I want to have a way to teach hudson to delete the complete workspace before doing a checkout & build. Is there a plugin which enables that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently, each SCM plugin provides workspace cleanup functionality.  Soon, core Hudson will have this capability, and the SCM plugins will migrate the setting to that core feature:
[issue 3966](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-3966)

Answer (score 7):

Under Source Code Management, expand the advanced properties and un-check "Use Update" (this option is present for me for CVS, not sure about all other SCM tools). This option controls if Hudson uses an "update" command to simply grab changed files from SCM, or if it checks out a new/clean copy from source control.

Comment: It's present for all the SCM tools

Comment: And, in addition, do a 'clean' (like: 'maven clean') to remove the previous build artifacts as well (in maven: the target folder)

Comment: does that actually deletes the complete workspace? maven clean is not enough, I want to delete the local repository as well.

Comment: You mean you want to delete the local Maven repository? If so, I think that falls outside of the scope of what Hudson will do for you

Comment: I configured a private maven repository, only used by this job, so it actually is located within the workspace.

Answer (score 3):

There is an option under `Advanced Project Options`: Clean workspace before build.

It does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Uncheck Use Update under SCM options **AND** use call maven's clean phase in your command.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used them yet, but AFAIK there are hudson-plugins available which allow batch scripts to run as pre- and post-build steps which could delete the directory.
Check out: Manage Hudson -> Manage Plugins -> Available

Answer (score 0):

The Subversion plugin for Hudson now has a switch to "Emulate Checkout" -- it removes unversioned files before reverting and updating.